# How to load HTML file from another assembly to WPF WebBrowser Control

Tags: html, wpf, webbrowser-control

These are the projects in my solution:

- HTMLApp (TypeScript) - contains index.html
- WebBrowserApp (WPF) - contains main.xaml with WebBrowser control

I want to load the content of index.html into the web browser control inside main.xaml. Build Action of index.html is set as Resource.

I tried this code in the XAML but did not work:

```
myBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/HtmlApp/index.html"));
```

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just put index.html as a resource in a library project and then reference that from the other two projects?

Comment: @MarkFeldman no particular reason. just now i created a sample class library with index.html as a resource then referenced it from WebBrowserApp. i'm still getting "Cannot find.. Make sure the path is correct" when i used both siteoforigin and application packs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` control doesn't work with [pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

The `Source` of the `Uri` that you pass to the `Navigate` method is supposed to be a URL or an absolute file path. The `WebBrowser` control doesn't support browsing resources or relative paths.

You could change the `Build Action` of `index.html` to `Content`, set the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer` and then navigate to the local file like this:

```
myBrowser.Source = new Uri(string.Format("file:///{0}/index.html", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```